# Showing value between 2 dates using measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

I've a table like below in Power BI with only the start and end date with the value between this dates.

| Start_date | End_date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 2020-12-03 | 7 |
| 2020-12-04 | 2020-12-17 | 8 |
| 2020-12-18 | 2020-12-21 | 6 |
| 2020-12-22 | 2099-12-31 | 7 |

How could I show the value of a specific day *(e.g. on 2020-12-20 the show value be 6)* using a measure?

Answer (score 1):

If your specific day is in DateTable then write for example:

```
Measure = calculate( max('Table'[Value]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), 
'Table'[Start_date]<=  SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[Date])  
&&   SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[Date])  <=  'Table'[End_date]  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you set the specific day using a slicer `DimDate[Date]`.

Then you can write your measure like this:

```
Measure =
VAR DateSelected = SELECTEDVALUE ( DimDate[Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[Start_date] <= DateSelected &&
            Table1[End_date] >= DateSelected
        ),
        Table1[Value]
    )
```